# Read CSV and loop through in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to Import a list of endpoints I have which is saved to a CSV, Loop through the list and Display the DeviceName, Owner, Depatment, Jobtitle. Please help.

```
$Endpoints = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Ryan\Endpoints.csv"
$Result = @()
$Users = Get-AzureADDevice -filter $Endpoints.Endpoint | select DisplayName, objectID
$Users | ForEach -Object {
  $user = $_
  Get-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -All $true |
    ForEach -Object {
      $Result += New-Object PSObject -property @{
        DeviceOwner = $_.DisplayName
        DeviceName = $user.Displayname
        Department = $_.Department
        Jobtitle = $_.Jobtitle
      }
    }
}
$Result | Select DeviceOwner, DeviceName, Department, Jobtitle
```

I had this working without Import using a static Endpoint Name e.g. `$Users = Get-AzureADDevice -SearchString "LaptopName"`

Comment: Your code has syntactical errors but basically you need to loop over your CSV and query `Get-AzureADDevice` on each iteration

Comment: It looks like you have a typo: `$_Get-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner`. Also, please indent your code properly to make it easier to read.

Comment: Sorry that that was a typo i will edit that

Answer (score 3):

Based on assumptions this might be what you're looking for, note the outer loop to iterate over each row of your CSV:

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Ryan\Endpoints Society\Desktop\Endpoint.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $devices = Get-AzureADDevice -SearchString $_.Endpoint
    if(-not $devices) { return "$($_.EndPoint) not found, skipping" }
    foreach($device in $devices) {
        foreach($owner in Get-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner -ObjectId $device.ObjectId -All $true) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                DeviceOwner = $owner.DisplayName
                DeviceName  = $device.Displayname
                Department  = $owner.Department
                Jobtitle    = $owner.Jobtitle
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Santiago, how is that code looking at the imported file its not assigned a variable?

Comment: @starplus yup, you don't really need to save the CSV in a variable, you can stream the results, the output generated by `Import-Csv` is being passed through the pipeline and iterated over with `ForEach-Object`

Comment: Got it the code worked - Thanks a lot apricate the help

Comment: @starplus glad to hear it worked :) the loop `foreach($device in $devices) {` might not be needed but up to you to test it.

Answer (score 2):

### Not your answer, but how to find it

This script suffers greatly from 'one-liner-itis'.  It is very hard to follow and going to be impossible to debug because of its over-the-top reliance on pipes and `foreach-object` commands§

Step one to make this even testable is to unwrap these commands into stand-alone commands, then you can debug line by line and see what the values are at that line.

```
$Endpoints = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Ryan\Endpoints.csv"
 
$Result=@()
$devices= Get-AzureADDevice -filter $Endpoints.Endpoint | 
    select DisplayName, objectID

#for debugging, we will only look at the first two devices
$devices = $devices[0..1]

foreach($device in $devices){
    $thisDeviceOwners = $_Get-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner -ObjectId  $user.ObjectId -All $true

    foreach($owner in $thisDeviceOwners){
       $Result += New-Object PSObject -property @{ 
          DeviceOwner = $_.DisplayName
          DeviceName = $user.Displayname
          Department = $_.Department
          Jobtitle = $_.Jobtitle
          }
    }
}
    $Result | Select DeviceOwner, DeviceName, Department, Jobtitle
```

Next, just run this one time in your IDE of choice, like PowerShell ISE or Visual Studio Code, then look to see what values you have for these variables.  One of them will be empty or odd, and therein lies your problem:

- $device
- $devices
- $thisDeviceOwners
- $owner

Note that I changed `$devices` to only be the first two items in `$devices`, so you can see how the code is working.  Find and fix your problem with one or two items and then the whole script will likely work.

§ - there is *nothing wrong with* your approach, and in fact PowerShell was built from the ground up to be like the Unix Bash Shell, loads of small commands that do one thing, and can be used to pass results on to the next command.  It allows for ad-hoc powerful control.

But in an enterprise script, we should not use one-liners and should instead use commonly accepted coding practices.  Each *line of code* should do only one thing, and shouldn't wrap around.

Comment: i would remove the `$Result +=` and just capture the output of the loop into the collection directly. try to avoid teaching that structure with arrays since it doesn't do what it seems to do. [*grin*] lookee ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays?view=powershell-7.2#plus-equals-

Comment: `Get-AzureADDevice -filter $Endpoints.Endpoint` doesn't like something that would work assuming its an array, and it's not a valid filter synatx either

Comment: Thats a good point, Lee, PowerShell is often taught with layers of 'do this', then later you find out 'actually you should not ever do that'